# How is structural damage to a composite fuselage detected?

Tags: aircraft-design, safety, boeing-787, airbus-a350

When a service vehicle collides with the aircraft, the plastic nature could hide any subsurface fractures which could propagate as the aircraft goes through cycles.

How is potential damage diagnosed on the A350 or 787?

Comment: Related: [A review of non-destructive testing methods of composite materials](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2452321616000093) and [The Challenges Of Detecting Composite Damage](http://www.aviationpros.com/article/11666312/the-challenges-of-detecting-composite-damage)

Answer (score 1):

I can't personally speak for the Airbus, or Boeing methodology regarding damage diagnosis, however speaking as an A&P IA FCC, experienced in the Business, and General Aviation Industry, the diagnosis will employ, one or a combination of all of the following inspection methods:

- Visual
- Coin-Tap
- X-Ray
- Ultrasonic

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE, while this is correct, it would be good to explain them a bit more and maybe provide some links to further reading.